# Unable to create mentionOf relation (ProvToolBox - org.openprovenance.prov)

Tags: java

I'm currently working on a project with the ProvToolBox library. Among other things, I would like to connect entities using the mentionOf relation, however I always encounter the same error when calling ".newMentionOf":

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openprovenance.prov.model.ObjectFactory.createMentionOf()" because "this.of" is null

I understand the error but I haven't been able to fix it so far: Provfactory's ObjectFactory is null ("this.of"). I was able to create other entities without problems (entities, bundles,WasDerivedFrom, ect) but for "mentionOf" this always happens.

My ProvFactory is created like this:
InteropFramework.getDefaultFactory();

I looked in the documentation to try to configure the ObjectFactory but it's not possible. I also tried to create the ProvFactory in another way, but I was not successful either (tried another method from InteropFramework, ModelConstructor, ObjectFactory...).

Also checked the code execution and, indeed, the "of" object (objectFactory) of the ProvFactory instance is always null, since its creation. I'm using **org.openprovenance.prov.model** package, but upon further inspection, I realized that the previous entity creation methods were actually redirected to the ProvFactory class from **org.openprovenance.prov.vanilla**. The newmentionOf method is not capable of doing this because there is no similar method, hence the error. Also, it's worth noting that the vanilla version uses the ModelConstructor creation methods instead of the ObjectFactory, but the ModelConstructor version of "newMentionOf" does literally nothing other than throw an exception:

public MentionOf newMentionOf(QualifiedName e2, QualifiedName e1, QualifiedName b) {
throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

Any ideas how to create a mentionOf relation ? Thank you